# What are the reasons AWS EC2 status check fails?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an instance on AWS free tier `t3.micro`.

The problem I faced is suddenly my instance was not able to connect with other instances.

I have checked on the dashboard and see that on the status check column it was showing `1/2` checks passed while another instance is `2/2` passed

On the Alarm status column, it was showing `1/2` in alarm.

I check on alarm details and it was showing a green tick on CPU utilization while the red triangle icon is showing on status check failed.

I also check the monitoring of the instance and found that the status checks failed graph has 1 count.

I have restarted the machine and now it is `2/2` passed.

What are the reasons AWS EC2 status check fails?

Answer (score 1):

Here, you can find a full list of reasons why status checks fail and how can you enable alarms too which can initiate recovery.

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-linux-status-check-failure/